# Using insertBefore with Anonymous Content (XBL) not working as expected in Firefox Add-On

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, firefox-addon, xul

I am trying to add a dropmarker to the Firefox Search Bar. Most of it is Anonymous Content implemented in XBL. I want to start by adding an hbox container among the anonymous child contents of searchbar, which is the code below:

```js
var dropmarker_hbox = document.createElement("hbox");
dropmarker_hbox.setAttribute("anonid", "searchhistory-dropmarker-container");
dropmarker_hbox.setAttribute("class", "searchhistory-dropmarker-container");
var searchbar = document.getElementById("searchbar");
var textbox = document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute(searchbar, "anonid", "searchbar-textbox");
var hbox = document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute(textbox, "class", "autocomplete-textbox-container");
var go_hbox = document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute(searchbar, "class", "search-go-container");

textbox.insertBefore(dropmarker_hbox, go_hbox);
```

The result as viewed in the DOM Inspector:[XUL Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sqse.png)

So I am having two problems. First I want my "searchhistory-dropmarker-container" to show up right before Firefox's "search-go-container", but insertBefore is not working as expected.

Second issue is that the DOM structure suggests I should be adding my container to "autocomplete-textbox-container" and not "searchbar-textbox". But doing that causes an object not found exception with insertBefore and just silently fails with appendChild.

So why can't I add objects to "autocomplete-textbox-container"? How do I position my "searchhistory-dropmarker-container" right before "search-go-container"? I am guessing insertBefore is not working as expected because "search-go-container" is not a direct child of "searchbar-textbox".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that what you are looking at is a combination of multiple XBL bindings - meaning that things get complicated. First there is `chrome://browser/content/search/search.xml#searchbar` applying to the actual `<searchbar>` tag:

```xml
<xul:stringbundle/>

<xul:textbox class="searchbar-textbox" anonid="searchbar-textbox">
  <xul:box>
    <xul:button>
      ...
    </xul:button>
  </xul:box>
  <xul:hbox class="search-go-container">
    <xul:image class="search-go-button" anonid="search-go-button" />
  </xul:hbox>
</xul:textbox>
```

Here you can see that "search-go-container" is a child of the textbox element (feel free to check its `parentNode` property in DOM Inspector to verify this). But that structure is being overlayed by `chrome://global/content/bindings/autocomplete.xml#autocomplete` applying to the `<textbox>` tag:

```xml
<xul:hbox class="autocomplete-textbox-container">
  <children includes="image|deck|stack|box">
    <xul:image class="autocomplete-icon"/>
  </children>

  <xul:hbox anonid="textbox-input-box" class="textbox-input-box">
    <children/>
    <html:input anonid="input"/>
  </xul:hbox>

  <children includes="hbox"/>
</xul:hbox>

<xul:dropmarker anonid="historydropmarker" class="autocomplete-history-dropmarker"/>

<xul:popupset anonid="popupset" class="autocomplete-result-popupset"/>

<children includes="toolbarbutton"/>
```

Note the multiple `<children>` tags marking the insertion points for child nodes of that text box. It looks like your element got inserted at the `<children includes="image|deck|stack|box">` insertion point rather than the `<children includes="hbox">` one - it seems that Gecko cannot correctly handle all the various insertion points dynamically.

You can simply append your box to the "autocomplete-textbox-container" element however:

```js
hbox.appendChild(dropmarker_hbox);
```

This seems counter-intuitive but it will actually add your element before the "search-go-container" - because "search-go-container" isn't an actual child but rather added at the end of the real child nodes by XBL.